# NX Angular Storybook not building

Tags: angular, storybook, nrwl-nx, angular-storybook

After running nx migrate our Storybook stories are building with errors such as:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs'
ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
........
```

I have tried npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular but still getting errors.

This is the output from nx version:

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.7
Node: 10.20.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.2.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.7
@angular/cdk                    10.2.2
@angular/cli                    11.0.7
@angular/material               10.2.2
@angular/platform-server        10.1.2
@angular/youtube-player         10.0.1
@schematics/angular             11.0.7
@schematics/update              0.1100.7
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is not the answer but might help someone figure this out.
I found a related article
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13093

basically I edited this file:

```
storybook/app/angular/src/server/angular-cli_utils.ts
```

Searched for this string:

```
'@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs'
```

and replaced it with:

```
'@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs'
```

This allowed my Stories to build again. Finally.
This is only a temp hack.

Anyone has a better solution?

Comment: Where is `storybook/app/angular/src/server/angular-cli_utils.ts`? Under node_mods? My package is `@storybook/angular` and it doesn't have a src folder...